# Is there a way to keep an object in bounds in pygame, and make it move when you hold the directional keys down?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame 1.9.6 and python 3.7.7. I am looking for a way to have something drawn by pygame(or maybe even an image) that stays inside the window border(and stops when I release the key. I started with the “if keys[]:” method:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x>0:
    x-=speed
```

that made it stay in bounds, but it only moved a few pixels and then did not repeat.
Next I tried the “event.key” method:

```
if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
        xchange=-speed
        ychange=-0
```

but that just makes the object move forever. I tried putting “and x>0” on the same line right after the direction, an “if x>0:” before, an “if x<0:” after, but the event never updates to see that the coordinates are past the edge, even with update commands. It just keeps going and going. I also don’t know how to make the object stop moving when I release the key, since event.key’s have the event always on.

Thank you for all the help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

In order for something to stay within a frame, you must check if it's coordinates are not past the border before moving it.

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if(keys[K_LEFT]):
    if(square.left > 0):
        square.left -= 10
if(keys[K_RIGHT]):
    if(square.right < 600):
        square.left += 10
if(keys[K_UP]):
    if(square.top > 0):
        square.top -= 10
if(keys[K_DOWN]):
    if(square.bottom < 600):
        square.bottom += 10
```

This is an example of how you would do this with a Rect object, it checks for border and then moves the object if its within those border and the appropriate key is being pressed. I can't apply this to your code as I cannot see enough of it but you just have to replace the coordinates. For example, you might have thing.x instead of square.left